# Hudson ajp port / service unavailable

Tags: apache2, hudson, ajp

I just installed hudson 3.1.2 on ubuntu server 14 using the apt-get install hudson command line.

Once the installation was done, I changed the default configuration file so I can access hudson using /hudson in the url. I also configured the http port and ajp port like the following:

```
HTTP_PORT=8082
AJP_PORT=8029
HUDSON_ARGS="--prefix=/hudson --webroot=/var/run/hudson/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
```

When restarted, everything worked fine.

I then configured my workers.properties file in apache2 configuration directory as follow:

```
worker.list=worker1,artifactory,hudson

worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009

worker.artifactory.type=ajp13
worker.artifactory.host=localhost
worker.artifactory.port=8019

worker.hudson.type=ajp13
worker.hudson.host=localhost
worker.hudson.port=8029
```

And also the default enabled site as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        JkMount /penny* worker1
        JkMount /manager* worker1
        JkMount /artifactory* artifactory
        JkMount /hudson* hudson
        JkMount /jira* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

When typing the full ip address and port, I can access Hudson without any issue, when accessing using the ipaddress/hudson, I get the Service Unavailable message from apache, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

JkMount /hudson* hudson -- You can remove "*" after "/hudson" from the configuration and verify. It should work.

I am sure you would have enable Mod_JK module.

Can you please post jenkins configuration file.

And Full worker.properties file.

Comment: I did and it didn't change anything